# Yum install: unexpected nothing to do while upgrading elasticsearch

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, upgrade, elasticsearch

I'm experimenting something estrange with yum in centos7, lets see If someone understands what's happening:

Usually, I upgrade packages using `sudo yum install <package_name>-<version_info>`, for example, right now, I'm trying to do an upgrade of `elasticsearch` package from `v6.7.1` to `7.1.1`. To do that, I first need (suggested by the Elasticsearch documentation) to upgrade to `6.8.0`, so I executed `yum install elasticsearch-6.8.0` and the package was correcty upgraded.

Now, if I check the version of Elasticsearch, I got:

```bsh
[root@centos7 vagrant]# rpm -qa | grep elasticsearch
elasticsearch-6.8.0-1.noarch
```

Now, I add the Elasticsearch repositories for `7.x` with:

```bsh
# rpm --import https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
# cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/elastic.repo << EOF
[elasticsearch-7.x]
name=Elasticsearch repository for 7.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
EOF
```

and check that the package elasticsearch-7.1.1 exists and is available:

```bsh
[root@centos7 vagrant]# yum --showduplicates list elasticsearch | expand | grep 7.
elasticsearch.noarch                 6.7.0-1                  elasticsearch-6.x 
elasticsearch.noarch                 6.7.1-1                  elasticsearch-6.x 
elasticsearch.noarch                 6.7.2-1                  elasticsearch-6.x 
elasticsearch.x86_64                 7.0.0-1                  elasticsearch-7.x 
elasticsearch.x86_64                 7.0.1-1                  elasticsearch-7.x 
elasticsearch.x86_64                 7.1.0-1                  elasticsearch-7.x 
elasticsearch.x86_64                 7.1.1-1                  elasticsearch-7.x 
elasticsearch.x86_64                 7.2.0-1                  elasticsearch-7.x
```

But, if I try to install `elasticsearch-7.1.1` using `yum install` I got:

```bsh
[root@centos7 vagrant]# yum install elasticsearch-7.1.1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.tedra.es
 * extras: mirror.gadix.com
 * updates: mirror.gadix.com
Nothing to do
```

And, if I try to use upgrade-to, I found this interesting issue:

```
[root@centos7 vagrant]# yum upgrade-to elasticsearch-7.1.1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.tedra.es
 * extras: mirror.gadix.com
 * updates: mirror.gadix.com
Package(s) elasticsearch-7.1.1 available, but not installed.
No packages marked for update
```

Package(s) elasticsearch-7.1.1 **available, but not installed.**

If I try just, `yum install elasticsearch` it let me upgrade to 7.2.0

What could be going on? why yum said elasticsearch is not installed? Look at the output of the following command:

```bsh
[root@centos7 vagrant]# yum list installed | grep elasticsearch
elasticsearch.noarch               6.8.0-1                    @elasticsearch-6.x
kibana.x86_64                      6.8.0-1                    @elasticsearch-6.x
logstash.noarch                    1:6.8.0-1                  @elasticsearch-6.x
```

I hope someone can help me. Greetings and thank you very much.

**Edit**

Running with `--verbose` don't give us so much more information

```bsh
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Config time: 0.005
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Package Sacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.tedra.es
 * extras: mirror.gadix.com
 * updates: mirror.gadix.com
pkgsack time: 0.009
Building updates object
up:Obs Init time: 0.069
up:simple updates time: 0.004
up:obs time: 0.001
up:condense time: 0.000
updates time: 0.148
Nothing to do
```

If I try to download the package manually and install it I can upgrade without any problem, but I would like to understand what happening with the repository.

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.1.1-x86_64.rpm
yum install elasticsearch-7.1.1-x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Sometimes, running `yum` in `--verbose` gives clues, e.g. excluded, obsoleted packages and dependency resolution issues. Could you add that info?

Comment: Thanks, Edward, I forgot to put that info because it does not contribution much information. I've added it anyway.

Comment: I've been busy trying to replicate your issue, but I can't. `yum install elasticsearch-7.1.1` does the trick every time. Are you *sure* there aren't any `exclude` lines still present anywhere in the yum config tree?

Comment: I encountered a very similar problem on a totally different package and I believe it relates to the architecture of the package changing. It seems that when going from `noarch` to native (`x86_64`) or back again, yum gets confused. I can't find any solid documentation on this, though.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same problem trying to upgrade to 7.8.1 from 6.8.10 and current latest release is 7.9.0. My solution was to do `yum install elasticsearch` and install latest version then `yum downgrade elasticsearch-7.8.1-1.x86_64` to downgrade to the previous version.